# Does networkx provide a method to create a subgraph of all possible paths which can be taken from one node?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, pyvis

I have a graph showing the relationships between objects where if object A interacts with object B, and object B interacts with object C, I must assume object A could transitively interact with object C.

I can get a set of all of these paths using the `nx.descendants`.

I would also like to display a graph showing these transitive relationships - is there a similar method that returns a graph rather than a set?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by taking the descendants (plus the source) and making a copy of the [subgraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) induced by these nodes:

```py
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_edges_from([("a", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "d"), ("b", "e")])

In [4]: descendants = nx.descendants(G, "b")

In [5]: descendants
Out[5]: {'c', 'd', 'e'}

In [6]: descendants.add("b")

In [7]: H = G.subgraph(descendants).copy()

In [8]: H.adj
Out[8]: AdjacencyView({'b': {'c': {}, 'e': {}}, 'c': {'d': {}}, 'd': {}, 'e': {}})

In [9]: list(H.edges)
Out[9]: [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Note that this will only include edges which exist in the original graph, e.g. `('b', 'c')` and `('c', 'd')`, but not `('b', 'd')`. This relationship is implied by the structure of the graph, but to add edges which fill in these implied relationships (the reachability relation), you can take the [transitive closure](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_closure.html):

```
In [15]: list(nx.transitive_closure(H).edges)
Out[15]: [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

These algorithms actually work for all directed graphs, not just DAGs.